# Dynamic css file 304 on Chrome but 200 on FF and IE?

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, httpresponse, http-status-code-304

I have a css file being dynamically loaded. For example:

```
http://example.com/css.php?request=/skin/styles.css
```

On chrome is loads very fast and it has the `304 not modified` header.

On FF and IE it has `200 OK` status and loads in 6 seconds!

If I have a static css file for example:

```
http://example.com/styles.css
```

I get the `304 not modified` on all browsers.

Any ideas what could be causing this? There is no browser specific rules in htaccess or httpd.conf

Comment: I would say that even with full re-load, 6 seconds for a CSS file is **extremely** bad.

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with chrome recognizing and caching the stylesheet, but FF and IE don't realize they are receiving a stylesheet.

Comment: Compare the caching headers using Fiddler.

Comment: One suggestion I have: Are you sending correct mime type when outputting the file via PHP?

Comment: Hi, I have fixed the issue. though i was update in canse anyone else has the same problem. I had this setting enabled in php:

`zlib.output_compression`

As soon as I disabled this it was lightning fast in Firefox.